# How to apply udf functions in a column which contain only null and true value

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with column names "x" and "Y", y column contain only null and true values,

```
x       y
br     null
br     null
bm     null
bm     null
br     true
bm     true
```

I need to create a udf which create a another column "z" and marks null as 1 and true as 0

```
x       y         z
br     null       1
br     null       1
bm     null       1
bm     null       1
br     true       0
bm     true       0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need an UDF for that. It's quite straightforward using the `when` and `otherwise` clauses :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df.withColumn("z", when(col("y").isNull(), 1).otherwise(0))
```